# Check value and alert

Tags: jquery, input, slider, alert

With some tools i've created a dynamic line graph. Through slider input visitors can change the graph. Now i want to check the value of the input slider and when it reaches a certain value it should give a alert.

Here is the code from my input slider:

```html
<input type="range" class=""oninput="$(this.nextElementSibling).trigger('f.change', this.value)" onchange="$(this.nextElementSibling).trigger('f.change', this.value)" data-f-bind="verhoogde aandacht" min="0" max="0.5" step="0.05">
<span class="range-value" data-f-bind="verhoogde aandacht"></span>
```

and this is my own written code to get the alert

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (.range === 0.014999999664724){
    alert( "Check" );
  };
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `.range` generates syntax error, which you can easily see in console.

Answer (score 1):

read documentation of jquery more detail.

You need listener to your element eg. i want check value if reached certain value.
You need check CHANGE VALUE. In jQuery you can use:

```
<input type="range" class="" data-f-bind="verhoogde aandacht" min="0" max="0.5" step="0.05">
<span class="range-value" data-f-bind="verhoogde aandacht"></span>

// document ready only bind object to jquery dom
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add on listener for listen changes in anytime
  $('input[type=range]').on('change', function(
     var value = $(this).val();

     if(value >= 0.01) {
        alert('check!');
     }
  });
});
```

change http://api.jquery.com/change/
on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it looks like you just haven't defined the value you're comparing to 0.014999999664724.

Try this (if you're only using one input of type range in your code).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($(':input[type=range]') && $(this).val() === 0.014999999664724){
      alert( "Check" );
  };
});
```